# how to on change -radio button antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, antd

i have question arr and foreche question i want to render the question and antd radio button answers.

**the problem is** when i change any question, all the answer changed as well to the same answer that i change in the first question .
there is any way to do key or id to the radio button and on change by that key, or any help??
this is my code:

```
 import { Radio } from "antd";
 const { questions} = props;
 const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

 const onChange = e => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
};

{questions.map((question, i) => {                     
            return (<div><div>{question.Description}</div>
            <Radio.Group value={value} onChange={onChange} >
                 <Radio value={1}>Aי</Radio>
                 <Radio value={2}>B</Radio>
                 <Radio value={3}>C</Radio>
            </Radio.Group></div>) 
 })}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a state of array or create a child component for radio buttons to has own state:

```
import { Radio } from "antd";
const { questions} = props;
const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

const onChange = (e, i) => {
    setValue(prevState => {
        const newState = [...prevState]; 
        newState[i] = e.target.value;
        return newState;
    });
};

{questions.map((question, i) => {                     
    return (<div><div>{question.Description}</div>
        <Radio.Group value={value[i]} onChange={e => onChange(e,i)} >
             <Radio value={1}>Aי</Radio>
             <Radio value={2}>B</Radio>
             <Radio value={3}>C</Radio>
        </Radio.Group></div>) 
})}
```